# Get Jest test name within beforeEach() and afterEach()

Tags: jestjs

I am running Jest and am trying to log the start and end timestamp for each of my tests. I am trying to stick my timestamp logging inside the `beforeEach()` and `afterEach()` blocks. How would I log the name of my Jest test within the `beforeEach()` and `afterEach()` block?

Also, is there a more global way of logging test name and timestamp before and after all the tests without using `beforeEach()` and `afterEach()`?

Comment: For your second question, have you considered `beforeAll` and `afterAll` ?

Comment: @Dario - Sorry, I should have been more clear. I meant getting some global way to log the name and timestamp of each test. Unfortunately Jest does not have that information in `beforeAll()` and `afterAll()`.

Answer (score 19):

You can access the name of the current test in jest like this:

```js
expect.getState().currentTestName
```

This method also works inside `beforeEach` / `afterEach`

The only downside is that it will also contain the name of your current describe section. (which may be fine depending on what you are trying to do.

Also it does not give you the timing information that you asked for.

Comment: This return the describe name + test name, not specifically the test name

Comment: @JRichardsz that limitation was already part of my answer

Comment: Doesn't work for me: expect.getState is not a function

Answer (score 3):

The information on currently running test is unavailable in `beforeEach`. Similarly to Jasmine, suite object is available in Jest as `this` context in `describe` function, it's possible to patch spec definitions to expose needed data. A more trivial way would be to define custom wrapper function for global `it` that intercepts test name.

[Custom reporter](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#reporters-arraymodulename--modulename-options) is a better way to do this. Reporter interface is self-documented, necessary data is [available in `testResult`](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/packages/jest-test-result/src/types.ts#L81-L115).

Performance measurements are already available:

```
module.exports = class TimeReporter {
  onTestResult(test, testResult, aggregatedResult) {
    for (let { title, duration } of testResult.testResults)
        console.log(`test '${title}': ${duration} ms`);
  }
}
```

Can be used like:

```
reporters: ['default', "<rootDir>/time-reporter.js"]
```

As it was noted, there are `beforeAll` and `afterAll`, they run once per `describe` test group.

Comment: Using a reporter is exactly what I'm looking for. I'm using the latest version of Jest (26.0.1) but I do not see the `startTime` and `endTime` inside `testResult.testResults`. Is there a specific version of Jest that I need to use? I see `{ancestorTitles, duration, failureMessages, fullName, numPassingAsserts, status, title}` inside `testResult.testResults`.

Comment: Thanks for noticing. It seems I checked a different type. It currently stays the same. Start and end time are available as testResult.perfStats, in case you need them separately.

Comment: You're welcome. Unfortunately `testResult.perfStats` doesn't breakdown the start and end times for each test.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a test environment and either log times directly or write the name and timing info into a global variable that is only available inside the tests in question:

**./tests/testEnvironment.js**

```js
const NodeEnvironment = require('jest-environment-node');

class TestEnvironment extends NodeEnvironment {
    constructor(config, context) {
        super(config, context);
    }

    async setup() {
        await super.setup();
    }

    async teardown() {
        await super.teardown();
    }

    async handleTestEvent(event, state) {
        if (event.name === 'test_start') {
            // Log things when the test starts
        } else if (event.name === 'test_done') {
            console.log(event.test.name);
            console.log(event.test.startedAt);
            console.log(event.test.duration);
            this.global.someVar = 'set up vars that are available as globals inside the tests';
        }
    }

}

module.exports = TestEnvironment;
```

For each test suite the following comment is needed to use this environment:

```js
/**
 * @jest-environment ./tests/testEnvironment
 */
```

Also see https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testenvironment-string